# Call to async function not working as exptecd

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise, bluebird

I use the following code and the code is not getting to the if statement

```
function getContent(key) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../test.txt');
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        ....
        var fileKeyValObj = {};
        return fileKeyValObj[key];
    });
}
```

I was able to access to the return of the previous method via debug and its working ok... 
**Here the function is not getting to the if**

```
getContent('web', function (cmd) {
    if (typeof cmd !== 'undefined') {
```

Here the key is the web which I sent and I see that the return of the getContent is with the right value.

I see this post but I think that I did the same ,do I miss something here?
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Btw in this case its recommended to use **promise???** like blue bird

Comment: Returning data from an async callback is not doing what you want.  That's just returning back into the bowels of the file system code, not returning to any of your code.  You can't try to make an async operation suddenly be synchronous.  You just can't.  `getContent()` needs to either return a promise or accept a callback that you can call when the result is available.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is the `return` value in your callback for `fs.readfile` is not the effective return value for its containing function `getContent`.

When you pass a callback to `fs.readFile`, the function you pass in is *queued* to run *when* `fs.readFile` completes. In simple terms, `getContent` does the enqueuing and then says "My job's finished!" and returns (void), but `fs.readfile` is waiting for itself to complete before running the callback.

When `fs.readfile` runs its callback, it is *out of the context* of `getContent`. It will return, but "nobody will be there" to pick up the return value.

What you can do instead is pass in a callback to `getContent` which is then passed to `fs.readFile`.

```
function getContent(key, callback) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../test.txt');
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', callback);
}

getContent('web', function (error, data) {
    if (!error) {
        ... //Put your code here!
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }  
});
```

Now, `getContent` will run its second argument `function (error, data)` when `fs.readFile` completes.

Comment: Thanks, but after the readfile there is additional logic which I should use ,where should I put it?

Comment: Ok so what should I put in the callback in this case?

Comment: @JhonDree: You should place the `callback` call where you currently have placed your `return` statement.

Comment: @Bergi- Little bit confused can you please provide example? if you can help with promise its lot better ...

Comment: When I call `getContent`, I pass in two arguments: `web`, and `function (error, data)...`. That second argument becomes `callback` in the `getContent` function arguments. We then pass that same function into `fs.readFile`'s second argument, `callback`.

Comment: @analytalica - I understood that you pass two params as error and data but confused regard the callback ,can you edit your answer with what should I need to change please?

Comment: No, I mean, the `function` in the call to `getContent` *is* the `callback` argument.

Comment: So this is not the same of what have I tried already in my post?instead of callback I use inline function...

Comment: The difference is now you can access the data inside `//Put your code here!` which you could not do before.